# Wrong daily interval from UsageStatsManager

Tags: android, usage-statistics

I try to get app usage stats for yesterday from 21:00 to 21:00 by UTC, my time zone is UTC+3. 
My code:

```
    private String createReport() {
    UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    if (usageStatsManager != null) {
        List<UsageStats> usageStats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, getDateMillis(-1).first, getDateMillis(0).first);
        Log.i("Time", String.valueOf(getDateMillis(-1).first) + " " + String.valueOf(getDateMillis(0).first));
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        for (UsageStats temp: usageStats) {
            if (temp.getTotalTimeInForeground() > 0) {
                JSONObject post = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    post.put("Name", temp.getPackageName());
                    post.put("Duration", temp.getTotalTimeInForeground());
                    post.put("Date", dateFormat.format(temp.getLastTimeUsed()));
                    post.put("StartDate", dateFormat.format(temp.getFirstTimeStamp()));
                    post.put("LastDate", dateFormat.format(temp.getLastTimeStamp()));
                    post.put("MilisStartRange", String.valueOf(temp.getFirstTimeStamp()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                array.put(post);
            }
        }
        Log.i("Usage:", array.toString());
        return array.toString();
    }
    return "";
}

private Pair<Long,String> getDateMillis(long Day) {
    long result = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String date = " ";
    try {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd");
        date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        Date now = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        result = now.getTime() + Day * 86400000;
        date = dateFormat.format(new Date(result));
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return new Pair<>(result, date);
}
```

Input parameters for usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats are:

```
I/Time: 1528578000000 1528664400000
```

what is from

```
Sat Jun 09 2018 21:00:00 UTC and Sun Jun 10 2018 00:00:00 Local
```

to

```
Sun Jun 10 2018 21:00:00 UTC and Mon Jun 11 2018 00:00:00 Local.
```

but instead of that time period i get such output:

```
[{"Name":"com.google.android.youtube","Duration":10250,"Date":"2018-06-10 00:25:31","StartDate":"2018-06-09 14:30:01","LastDate":"2018-06-10 14:30:01","MilisStartRange":"1528543801139"},
...
{"Name":"com.lge.qmemoplus","Duration":10405,"Date":"2018-06-11 10:45:41","StartDate":"2018-06-10 14:39:18","LastDate":"2018-06-11 14:33:06","MilisStartRange":"1528630758448"}]
```

where system gives me 2 intervals:

```
from "2018-06-09 14:30:01" to "2018-06-10 14:30:01" 
and
from "2018-06-10 14:39:18" to "2018-06-11 14:33:06"
```

by my local UTC+3

My device is LG V30+ with Android 7.1.2 (API 25), also

```
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.yas.apptracker"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Pls help my, i can't understand what's wrong and if it's possible to fix this trouble

Also i get similar result in emulator (also 25) for today:

```
{"Name":"com.android.settings","Duration":885073,"Date":"2018-06-11 15:14:38","StartDate":"2018-06-11 10:42:20","LastDate":"2018-06-11 15:30:51","MilisStartRange":"1528702940536"},{"Name":"com.android.systemui","Duration":10705,"Date":"2018-06-11 15:14:39","StartDate":"2018-06-11 10:42:20","LastDate":"2018-06-11 15:30:51","MilisStartRange":"1528702940536"}
```